# Analyze system logs with logwatch --range other than just "yesterday"

Tags: logs, syslog

The manpage of `logwatch` says:

> The format of the range option is:
>       --range "date_range [period]"
>
> Parameter date_range (and optional period) must be enclosed in quotes
>   if it is ...
>
> Examples:
>
> --range today    --range yesterday    --range '4 hours ago for that
>   hour'    --range '-3 days'    --range 'since 2 hours ago for those
>   hours'    --range 'between -10 days and -2 days'    --range 'Apr 15,
>   2005'    --range 'first Monday in May'    --range 'between 4/23/2005
>   and 4/30/2005'    --range '2005/05/03 10:24:17 for that second'

but none of those options work on my Debian Squeeze machine.

How do you use the `--range` option correctly?

Comment: The examples are already given by you.  What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out myself:

if you scroll up the output after you try to call logwatch with --range, you see at the start:

> ERROR: Range '4 hours ago for that hour' not understood
>
> This system does not have Date::Manip module loaded, and therefore the
>   only valid --range parameters are 'yesterday', 'today', or 'all'. The
>   Date::Manip module can be installed by using either of:

```
apt-get install libdate-manip-perl
cpan -i 'Date::Manip'
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Date::Manip'
```

this takes quite a while to install, but then it works